# Script Help Moving Cell Values

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have a shared spreadsheet that I'm constantly having to correct. I'm trying to write a script that will move the cell value automatically if someone I have shared the sheet with puts information in the wrong column. I can clear the if statement for criteria, but I'm having troubles figuring out the code to move the value.
In column A I have rows 8-30 where numbers are entered. For the most part nothing should be put in column B except in certain circumstances (my if statement covers those). I want my script to take the value from the B column, keep it in the same row and add it to the cell in Column A. Then I want it to delete the value that was entered in the wrong spot. Can anyone help me with the syntax that helps me call the cell that gets edited, grab its value, add it one column over?

I'm starting with a very basic script and will qualify my if statement more later so I can make sure its working before making the IF statement more complicated. Thanks in advance for any help you can offer.

```
function onEdit(e) {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var r = ss.getActiveRange();


    if(r.getColumn() == 2 ) {
        \\ need calls for current cell value and adding I believe what is below will clear the cell that gets edited.
        spreadsheet.getRange(r).activate();
        spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From the question

> I want my script to take the value from the B column, keep it in the same row and add it to the cell in Column A. Then I want it to delete the value that was entered in the wrong spot. Can anyone help me with the syntax that helps me call the cell that gets edited, grab its value, add it one column over?

Take advantage of the Edit event object.

```js
/**
 * @param {Object} e Edit event object
 * @param {Range} e.range Edited range, it could have a single cell or multiple cells
 * @param {number|string|boolean|Date} [e.value] Edited cell value. It's only included when a single cell is edited
 */
function onEdit(e){
   var e = e || (() => { 
      var obj = {range: SpreadsheetApp.getCurrentCell()}; 
      obj.range.columnStart = obj.range.getColumn();
      return obj
   })();
// If the onEdit function is executed from the script editor use the active cell
  if(e.range.columnStart === 2){
     const editedCell = e.range.getCell(1,1); // Grabs the top right cell of edited range
     const value = e.value || editedCell.getValue(); // If only one cell is edited we could use e.value, otherwise we need to use getValue();
     editedCell.offset(0,-1).setValue(value);
     editedCell.clearContent();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably something like this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var s = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var col = e.range.columnStart;
  if (col != 2) return;

  var range = s.getActiveCell();
  var value = range.getValue();
  range.clearContent();
  range.offset(0,-1).setValue(value);
}
```

Or:

```
function onEdit() {
  var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell();
  if (cell.getColumn() != 2) return;
  var value = cell.getValue();
  cell.clearContent();
  cell.offset(0,-1).setValue(value);
}
```

But I don't understand, how can you full column 'B' if every new cell will automatically move to column 'A'? It seems column 'A' will be empty all the time.

And beware, in this version of the code if you will erase a cell in column 'B' (even if the cell is already empty) the script will erase a cell in column 'A' as well.

Comment: So to help clarify, the total in column A needs to not exceed a value, but if it is below the value, the number put in B needs to be moved to A until that is met. I didn't include all that in my if statement because the mechanic I was trying to figure out was moving the value over. Now that you have helped me with that, I've expanded my IF statement to account for that. Thank you!